# Cross origin Error when accessing image from Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cors

I have an application in which I have used Photosphereviewer js to display the image.

I have used node.js app and uploaded it to Azure web site (say: http://example1.com). The image used in Photosphereviewer is from another site (say: https://example2.com).

Now, When I am accessing the image from http://example1.com, It throws error as below

> Access to Image at 'https://example2.com/images/1.JPG' from origin
>   'http://example1.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example1.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

When I tried to use the image from another site inside  it displays the  image correctly without error.

But, when I used the image inside Photosphereviewer as below, it throws cors error:

```
var PSV = new PhotoSphereViewer({
                    panorama: 'https://example2.com/images/1.JPG',
                    container: 'photosphere',
                    caption: 'Images',
                    cors_anonymous: true,
                    checkImageOrigin: false,
                    // loading_img: 'http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/assets/photosphere-logo.gif',
                    navbar: 'autorotate zoom download caption', // fullscreen
                    // default_fov: 70,
                    mousewheel: false,
                    size: {
                      height: 520//472
                    }
                });
```

I have used cors in my app.js of node js app as below:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // We can access from anywhere
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');

  next();
});
```

In Azure web site I have included the site name under CORS option under Api section.

But none worked. It throws the same error. Please help to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you have any update?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your site `example2` which provides images, has the express static set like:
`app.use(express.static('public'));`,
and your image files may listed under the directory `public/images`.

I reproduced your issue with the above environment.

You can try to build a individual route in expressjs server to provide the images for your `PhotoSphereViewer` client:

```
app.get('/getimages/:filename',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/images/'+req.params.filename)
})
```

And in the forntend:

```
var PSV = new PhotoSphereViewer({
                panorama: 'https://example2.azurewebsites.net/getimages/1.jpg',
                container: 'photosphere',
                caption: 'Images',
                cors_anonymous: true,
                checkImageOrigin: false,
                // loading_img: 'http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/assets/photosphere-logo.gif',
                navbar: 'autorotate zoom download caption', // fullscreen
                // default_fov: 70,
                mousewheel: false,
                size: {
                  height: 520//472
                }
            });
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. My Image will be comming from amazon bucket and it throws cross origin error in photosphereviewer. So how i can allow cors in photosphereViewer??

Comment: As cors is a configuration on server side, you need to enable the CORS on your amazon bucket configuration.